# How to write a print function for custom stack class in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I'm want to write my own stack class and this is what I've written so far:

```
 public class Stack {

        private static class Node {
            private int data;
            private Node next;

            Node(int data) {
                this.data = data;
            }
        }

        Node top;

        public void push(int data) {
            Node node = new Node(data);
            if (top == null) {
                top = node;
                node.next = null;
                System.out.println(node);
            }
            node.next = top;
            top = node;
        }

        public void print() {...} // Help in completing this

    }
```

I've written others functions like peek and pop. But I need help in writing a `print` function that will print the elements of the stack without deleting them.

This is what I tried:

```
public void print() {
    Node node = top;
    while(node.next != null) {
        System.out.print(node.data + "  ");
        node = node.next;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an endless loop. It is printing all the elements but the last element is being printed infinitely. And I also think that the first line of the print function `Node node = top;` will create some problem, will it? I think it has to do something with referencing. `top` and `node` refers to the same memory location, am I right? Please tell me will it create a problem? Or is it correct?

Comment: Your stack class appears to just be a linked list. Have you looked up how to iterate a linked list?

Comment: What did you tried? Do you have problem with print top of the stack or second element?

Comment: Well, your `Stack` does contain a `next` element, so in `print()`, you print `data` and then call `next.print()`. This is called recursion and should be used carefully, as an endless recursion will lead to a stackoverflow within seconds. AND: make sure if `next` is an actuall object and not `null`.

Comment: One simple approach will be to create a temporary stack inside that method and keep on popping elements from your current stack and pushing them inside the temporary stack and before you pop print stack.top() and once your current stack is empty fill it again from temporary stack to your current stack... hope this helps

Comment: Args, little addition, I made a mistake. In have to start with `top.print()` and then go within that `print()` method with the `next.print()`. And that would require you to implement a `print()` method within `Node`

Comment: May I know the reason for this question being down voted? Is what I'm trying to do impossible? Can someone please give me the code for that print function?

Comment: @Carcigenicate How can I convert this linked list kind of class to a stack class?

Comment: @artenson.art98 You were likely downvoted because you haven't really shown any effort in solving it yourself. And your stack class *contains* a linked list; that's essentially what your `Node` class is. Think about how you get the next element of that stack once you have the first. That's what `next` holds. Once you have the second element of the stack, how do you get the third? And once you have the third, how do you get the fourth? And so on. Read up on linked lists. Someone just giving you the answer will only help you a little in the short term.

Comment: Linked lists are a fundamental structure in programming, and you *must* understand how to use them. Someone giving you the code for you to copy won't help you really learn the concept. Give this a read over: https://crunchify.com/how-to-implement-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch-in-java/ It seems to be a good introduction on how linked lists work.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for the link to crunchify.com. And I've changed my question and added the print function that I tried. And is it necessary to show the efforts here on stackoverflow? Thanks

Comment: @artenson.art98 Yes, it is necessary. This is not a site to have people tutor you, it's to ask a specific question and get a specific answer. How to write a print function for a linked list is way too broad, since it requires many different things. When you ask here, always show what you've tried to solve the problem, and what *specifically* you're having problems with. And I'm going out for a couple hours. When I get home, I'll look over the edited question.

Comment: If you're getting a infinite loop though, that would suggest that `node` is never being set to `null` when the end of the list is reached. Note how you never set `next` to null when you create a new `Node`.

Comment: Stick a `println` inside the loop to see what `node` is while it's looping infinitely. That's called "Print debugging". I use it more often than I do a debugger because it's so fast to use.

Comment: @Carcigenicate When the very first element is added, I set its next pointer to null explicitly as can be seen in the `if` block in the `push` function. But the last node's next pointer is never null. I tried print debugging by putting a `println` function inside the loop and outputted the next pointer of each node, but it is never getting `null`. - Thanks

Comment: The `push` method creates a loop. The last two lines of the `push` method should be inside an `else` part of the `if` statement.

Comment: @fgb Thanks, it worked. But I don't understand why it worked. Can you please explain in short? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in `print` is wrong. There the last two statements should be in an else block. There are 2 cases, when `top` is already set, and when it isn't. If both cases are run together, then they create a cycle in the list which will create an infinite loop when you try to print the stack.

This:

```
Node node = new Node(data);
```

Creates a new node and points `node` to this node. If `top` is null, then:

```
if (top == null) {
    top = node;
    node.next = null;
}
```

Sets `top` to point to this node, so `node` and `top` point to the same node.

Then:

```
node.next = top;
```

Sets `next` on this one node to point back to itself, because `node` and `top` are the same.